# Spiral with no beginning

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves, fractals

The spiral $r = \theta$ begins at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ for $\theta = 0$. Is there a type of spiral that continues spiralling as you zoom in near $(0,0)$? Like a fractal, with self similarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$  r = e^\theta $$

............................

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral